# docker ERROR: unknown blob

Tags: docker, docker-compose

On launching app using docker getting message  `ERROR: unknown blob` as per

```
docker-compose  -f /usr/local/tmp/khufu01/loud_deploy/nokube/dind/docker-compose.yml up -d 
Pulling myimage(localhost:5000/forelsket/myimage:latest)...
latest: Pulling from forelsket/myimage
50aff78429b1: Pulling fs layer
f6d82e297bce: Pulling fs layer
fdd34fec4c74: Pulling fs layer
151b5e27e3b4: Pulling fs layer
d477e9b677eb: Pulling fs layer
7e8156598779: Download complete
ca2064fc9543: Download complete
ERROR: unknown blob
```

after adding flag  --verbose to my docker-compose call it now shows

```
docker-compose --verbose  -f /usr/local/tmp/khufu01/loud_deploy/nokube/dind/docker-compose.yml up -d 
Pulling myimage(localhost:5000/forelsket/myimage:latest)...
latest: Pulling from forelsket/myimage
50aff78429b1: Pulling fs layer
f6d82e297bce: Pulling fs layer
fdd34fec4c74: Pulling fs layer
151b5e27e3b4: Pulling fs layer
d477e9b677eb: Pulling fs layer
7e8156598779: Download complete
ca2064fc9543: Download complete
ERROR: compose.cli.main.main: unknown blob
```

this is on linux using latest docker

```
docker 18.02.0-ce-rc2  
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-112-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
```

seems strange as this app ran fine this morning ... I am using a local docker repository of registry:2 at localhost:5000

Comment: Please refer my answer: [limit concurrent uploads/downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028844/github-packages-docker-error-pulling-image-configuration-unknown-blob/69970602#69970602)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solution  `ERROR: unknown blob` is trying to say one or more layers of the image is not found

... this makes sense since earlier today all local docker images were deleted

So after building the missing image the `docker-compose up` ran fine

Goes without saying this error can be avoided if a preliminary step first determines whether the image even exists in chosen image repository

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker`. Why doesn't that look safe? I wish I knew why you have to do that. It worked though.

Comment: To be precise, it says that a particular layer of the image is not found. The image still exists in the registry.

Comment: ERROR: unknown blob means: This error may be returned when a blob is unknown to the registry in a specified repository. This can be returned with a standard get or if a manifest references an unknown layer during upload.

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing `/var/lib/docker` made things worse - pulling failed with

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Pulling mysql-service (mysql:5.7.17)...
5.7.17: Pulling from library/mysql
6d827a3ef358: Pulling fs layer
ed0929eb7dfe: Pulling fs layer
03f348dc3b9d: Pulling fs layer
fd337761ca76: Waiting
7e6cc16d464a: Waiting
ca3d380bc018: Waiting
3fe11378d5c0: Waiting
2b5dfd325645: Waiting
b54281d17fbe: Waiting
7eae4db8eea5: Waiting
76cf68e17b09: Waiting
ERROR: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob310458906: no such file or directory
```

Purging docker solved the problem.