# SMTP4DEV - Docker pull error - Why get I Unkown Blob

Tags: docker, smtp4dev

When trying to get (pull or run) the docker smtp4dev, I've got the following error message : **/usr/bin/docker-current: unknown blob.**

I'm trying to run it from :

- a CentOS VM,
- with Docker version 1.13.1, build cccb291/1.13.1

Please find hereafter my terminal output

```
sudo docker run --rm -p 3001:80 -p 2525:25 rnwood/smtp4dev:3.1.0-ci2020052101
Unable to find image 'rnwood/smtp4dev:3.1.0-ci2020052101' locally
Trying to pull repository rnwood/smtp4dev ...
3.1.0-ci2020052101: Pulling from rnwood/smtp4dev
68ced04f60ab: Downloading [=======>                                           ] 3.898 MB/27.09 MB
4ddb1a571238: Downloading [===========>                                       ] 3.784 MB/17.06 MB
94b78a0446e2: Download complete
b48f8e1b0b06: Downloading
a41ea3d79519: Waiting
7064c9d40b9c: Waiting
/usr/bin/docker-current: unknown blob.
See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.
```

Thanks by advance for your support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599288/docker-error-unknown-blob

Comment: Dear @HamidAli, yes I guess this is the root cause. But I've post the question on the Github repo of the author to find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Florent did you find the solution? if yes then, care to share it with us?

Comment: Dear,
Still no solution...I'm still trying thinks. I'll update this post as soon as I get a solution.

Comment: Just to let you know I've run this command on ubuntu, and it seems to be working fine. Maybe it is something that helps you identify the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Following the new update of SMTP4DEV...it seems now working.. no root cause found...
The best hypothesis : problem with proxy network which leads to fail the build of the docker...
Stay tuned...