# rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error pulling image configuration: unknown blob when pull docker image

Tags: docker

I am pulling image from my local docker registry provider by nexus 3 in kubernetes cluster, but throw this error:

```
Failed to pull image "192.168.31.2:8080/goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error pulling image configuration: unknown blob
```

when I execute this command using docker in k8sslave3 host machine:

```
[root@k8sslave3 ~]# sudo docker pull 192.168.31.2:8080/goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.1
v2.0.1: Pulling from goharbor/harbor-portal
a10779388d4e: Pulling fs layer 
b3655b0b1b25: Pulling fs layer 
0c2039460571: Pulling fs layer 
7ea51f62bc90: Waiting 
9b7d884050ac: Waiting 
191f5a91ea62: Waiting 
a0935490d8f5: Waiting 
dd7dc6b4b30d: Waiting 
502017fcbb22: Waiting 
error pulling image configuration: unknown blob
```

I am read [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599288/docker-error-unknown-blob) and tell me the docker image does not exists. But when I execute pull in 192.168.31.2, the output like this:

```
[dolphin@localhost docker]$ sudo docker pull 192.168.31.2:8080/goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.1
[sudo] password for dolphin: 
v2.0.1: Pulling from goharbor/harbor-portal
Digest: sha256:d40f87352700cde0f91b9f758b3e47c9ebfe4358f73fa26a6675415b3fbc6b96
Status: Image is up to date for 192.168.31.2:8080/goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.1
192.168.31.2:8080/goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.1
```

so now I am confusing, what should I do to fix this problem? this is the docker image in nexus repository:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am read the question and tell me the docker image does not exists.
> But when I execute pull in 192.168.31.2, the output like this:

```
[dolphin@localhost docker]$ sudo docker pull 192.168.31.2:8080/goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.1
[sudo] password for dolphin: 
v2.0.1: Pulling from goharbor/harbor-portal
Digest: sha256:d40f87352700cde0f91b9f758b3e47c9ebfe4358f73fa26a6675415b3fbc6b96
Status: Image is up to date for 192.168.31.2:8080/goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.1
192.168.31.2:8080/goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.1
```

That is rather expected that it works if you pull the image from the host that hosts the registry.
As you created the tag from that host, the Docker client doesn't need to pull anything from the private registry, it returns directly the image from the local Docker registry of the host.
Look at the message :

> Status: Image is up to date for
> 192.168.31.2:8080/goharbor/harbor-portal:v2.0.1

Your image configuration/data is very probably corrupted in the registry.
Try to reupload it and check also that its size is not too big (several GBs may be too much sometimes) because it may create some troubles in registry uploading/storing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting Nexus in kubernetes, are you accessing it through an Ingress?

What may be happening is nginx (or other ingress) closing connection before image download is complete.  You may need to add additional annotations to allow for large images, and longer timeouts:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: '0'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '600'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '600'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '600'
```